In Ionic Android, Axios giving error Request Aborted but working fine in web browser
I am using Ionic for android and calling simple login post method using Axios. It is working fine in browser but in App it is showing following errors.
$e {message: 'Request aborted', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ECONNABORTED', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code
: 
"ECONNABORTED"
config

Here is my code
const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('username', username);
    formData.append('email  ', username);
    formData.append('password', password);
    formData.append('grant_type', 'password');

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(apiUrl, formData);

      if (response.status === 200) {
        const data = response.data;

        // Check if the data contains the expected fields
        if (data && data.access_token) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', data.access_token);
          history.push('dashboard');
        } else {
          setToastMessage('Invalid username or password.');
          setShowToast(true);
        }
      } else {
        setToastMessage('Failed to login. Please try again.');
        setShowToast(true);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error during login', error);
      setToastMessage('An error occurred. Please try again.');
      setShowToast(true);
    }

Got the issue and it is resolved
Issue was with SSL, I was using SSL for FastAPI instead of using Nginx Server, which was not trusted in Android it was rejecting

Check if you have internet permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file. Also check logs in your android studio.

I have checked, and all permissions are in place. Mostly issue with https, which is self signed

Got the issue, it was due to SSL (letsencrypt) for FastAPI which was not trusted by Android, so I used SSL for NGinx top of FastAPI and it worked.
